# sql With partition use in spark sql dataframe query

Tags: sql, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, with-statement

I have a sql query as such:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY TradedVolumSum DESC) AS rn
   FROM tempTrades
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

and I want to use it in spark sql to query my dataframe.

my dataframe looks like:
[image]

and I want to have only the maximum of tradedVolumSum for each day with the SecurityDescription. so I want to see something like:

[image]

how would I simulate same behaviour in spark sql in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for your problem assuming your data frame name is tempTrades:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

win_temp = Window.partitionBy(F.col("[date]")).orderBy(F.col("TradedVolumSum").desc())
tempTrades.withColumn(
    "rn",
    F.row_number().over(win_temp)
).filter(
    F.col("rn") == 1
)
```

Comment: In fact, may I ask another question?

Comment: thanks. the scenario I have is I need to compare the entries per day and report the differences. for example day one has records (a,b,c) , day two has(c,d,e) and day three has (f,g). I should report the set of a,b,c, d,e,f,g. this means for example company a,b,c had business on day one, then on day two business d and e added and day 3 f and g. I need to say what day which businesses are added to the system to do business

Comment: SELECT  [Date]
  ,securityDesc
  ,TradedVolumSum
  ,Mnemonic
FROM    (
        SELECT  [Date]
   ,securityDesc
   ,TradedVolumSum
   ,Mnemonic
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY Mnemonic DESC) AS rn
        FROM B6Table
        ) q
ORDER BY [Date]

Comment: this is the query I have and it can group by all days. all I would need to find newly added entries on each day and report same information (columns)

Comment: sorry but can you please ask the same question in different thread and share the link with me it would be helpful for others if they face the same issue. will answer the same in that thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140278/pyspark-sql-compare-records-on-each-day-and-report-the-differences    Thanks!