# PySpark sql compare records on each day and report the differences

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

so the problem I have is I have this dataset:

[image]

and it shows the businesses are doing business in the specific days. what i want to achieve is to report which businesses are added on what day. Perhaps Im lookign for some answer as:

[image]

I managed to tide up all the records using this sql:

```
select [Date]
,Mnemonic
,securityDesc
,sum(cast(TradedVolume as money)) as TradedVolumSum
FROM SomeTable
group by [Date],Mnemonic,securityDesc
```

but I dont know how to compare each days record with the other day and export the non existence record on the following day to another table. I tired sql over partition cluase but it makes it complex. I can either use sql or Pyspark sql python combination.

could you let me how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: does the below solution works for you?

Comment: Hi Ankit, sry I got busy with work and tried it just last night. It does I just need to change id to the SecurityId and it looks it produces same answer. Because there are too many files I have created a small sample which I ran my solution against it to test it. I havent done it yet with your solution but I think it should be ok. Will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the dataframe operation for your question you might need to tweak a little bit as I dont have the sample data for it, written the code by seeing your data, please let me know if that solves your problem:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

some_win = Window.partitionBy("securityDesc").orderBy(F.col("[date]").asc())
some_table.withColumn(
    "buisness_added_day",
    F.first(F.col("id")).over(some_win)
).select(
    "buisness_added_day",
    "securityDesc",
    "TradedVolumSum",
    "Mnemonic"
).distinct().orderBy("buisness_added_day").show()
```